# Hashing request - What type of hash this?

Tags: passwords

I have a text which is hashed using several layers of hashing. The final hash looks like `2E55A1DD65AB839E62362DEF86D329D7`. What type of hashing can it be? How can I find out what kind of hash sum I do have in a general way?

Comment: A 32 character long hex sequence is usually a MD5 hash

Comment: Do you have the ability to supply new inputs to the hash function(s) or do you just have the hashes themselves?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a hexadecimal representation of a 16 bytes (128 bit) hash output, which can be one of many hash functions, the most popular of them: MD5

But it can be [so many other hashes](http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash_identification.php) for example md2, md4, Haval, RipeMD etc...

And it can also be some transformation of some other hash function, for example computing a Sha1 hash and taking only first/last 128 bits

If it would have been a popular hash of a popular password with no layering, you could have found it in rainbow tables... But with layering there is no way to tell

Answer (score 2):

Just run the hash through a program like [hash-identifier](https://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/). The output of your hash is below.

```
root@kali:~# hash-identifier 
   #########################################################################
   #     __  __             __       ______    _____       #
   #    /\ \/\ \           /\ \     /\__  _\  /\  _ `\     #
   #    \ \ \_\ \     __      ____ \ \ \___ \/_/\ \/  \ \ \/\ \    #
   #     \ \  _  \  /'__`\   / ,__\ \ \  _ `\      \ \ \   \ \ \ \ \       #
   #      \ \ \ \ \/\ \_\ \_/\__, `\ \ \ \ \ \      \_\ \__ \ \ \_\ \      #
   #       \ \_\ \_\ \___ \_\/\____/  \ \_\ \_\     /\_____\ \ \____/      #
   #        \/_/\/_/\/__/\/_/\/___/    \/_/\/_/     \/_____/  \/___/  v1.1 #
   #                                 By Zion3R #
   #                            www.Blackploit.com #
   #                               Root@Blackploit.com #
   #########################################################################

   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HASH: 2E55A1DD65AB839E62362DEF86D329D7

Possible Hashs:
[+]  MD5
[+]  Domain Cached Credentials - MD4(MD4(($pass)).(strtolower($username)))

Least Possible Hashs:
[+]  RAdmin v2.x
[+]  NTLM
[+]  MD4
[+]  MD2
[+]  MD5(HMAC)
[+]  MD4(HMAC)
[+]  MD2(HMAC)
[+]  MD5(HMAC(Wordpress))
[+]  Haval-128
[+]  Haval-128(HMAC)
[+]  RipeMD-128
[+]  RipeMD-128(HMAC)
[+]  SNEFRU-128
[+]  SNEFRU-128(HMAC)
[+]  Tiger-128
[+]  Tiger-128(HMAC)
[+]  md5($pass.$salt)
[+]  md5($salt.$pass)
[+]  md5($salt.$pass.$salt)
[+]  md5($salt.$pass.$username)
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass.$salt))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass.$salt))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($salt.$pass))
[+]  md5($salt.md5(md5($pass).$salt))
[+]  md5($username.0.$pass)
[+]  md5($username.LF.$pass)
[+]  md5($username.md5($pass).$salt)
[+]  md5(md5($pass))
[+]  md5(md5($pass).$salt)
[+]  md5(md5($pass).md5($salt))
[+]  md5(md5($salt).$pass)
[+]  md5(md5($salt).md5($pass))
[+]  md5(md5($username.$pass).$salt)
[+]  md5(md5(md5($pass)))
[+]  md5(md5(md5(md5($pass))))
[+]  md5(md5(md5(md5(md5($pass)))))
[+]  md5(sha1($pass))
[+]  md5(sha1(md5($pass)))
[+]  md5(sha1(md5(sha1($pass))))
[+]  md5(strtoupper(md5($pass)))

   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```